# dnf showing unformatted strings

Tags: fedora, dnf

I'm assuming I've changed a setting, but I have no idea what and I haven't been able to find an answer via google.

When I run dnf, it prints the raw or unformatted strings with the format values:

```
sudo dnf upgrade
Loaded plugins: %s | ('builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync',)
DNF version: %s | ('4.2.5',)
Command: %s | ('dnf upgrade ',)
Installroot: %s | ('/',)
Releasever: %s | ('29',)
cachedir: %s | ('/var/cache/dnf',)
Base command: %s | ('upgrade',)
Extra commands: %s | (['upgrade'],)
```

This is on Fedora release 29.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem just went away. I'm not sure when. I have no idea how it was fixed so if someone else comes across this post while having this problem, I'm sorry I can't be of any help.